# how to use wget to download every image on a website?

Tags: image, pagination, wget

Seen lots of questions on this but here's my scenario:

If the website is `http://apple.foozbar.com/fizz` (I made that up) and the fizz page has pagination.  eg: `fizz/page/2?ref=pagination`, `fizz/page/3?ref=pagination`, and so on and so forth. And the images may or may not have an extension such as `.jpg`, `.gif`, etc etc. Maybe the images are in this format: `fozzbar.com/images/3454334/`

what `wget` command would I need to use to go through each pagination and download every image put on the page even if the images do not have an image extension?  could `wget` detect if the content posted on the website is an image and just detect only the images on the specific website location?

Comment: I forgot this is a "tell us what you tried or else no help.." site...

This is what I tried so far: wget -r -P directory/to/save/images/to -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://sitetodownloadimagesfrom

Comment: This is because so many guys abuse and think SO as a free coding service

Comment: I don't think `wget` is the right tool here. You have to script a bit, in shell or any language

Answer (score 0):

Basically, as a starter in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
set -eo pipefail

url="http://apple.foozbar.com"
for i in {1..100}; do
  mech-dump --images "${url}/fizz/page/$i?ref=pagination" |
    xargs -I% wget "$url"%
done
```

You need to install `mech-dump` utility from `libwww-mechanize-perl` (debian)

Comment: thanks! now I have to study the code you just posted up :) for me, it's not just asking people to post up code.  I also try to understand the code that is posted.  saves me time and helps me learn.  I have no idea what debian or perl code is.